# What is the mechanism of contacts syncing in any mobile application?

Tags: android

i have a question regarding - how contacts are synced between your android app and server to retreive particular contacts just like whatsapp? Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to add permission to read the device contacts and then you'll have access to them. There's a guide here: https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html

Comment: Thank you that you answered. But my problem lies in checking contacts with app's contact database available on server.

Comment: Do you mean the contacts connected to a users Google account? If so it's more than likely they would be synced with the contacts on the phone anyway, but if you must get the contact list from Google you'll need to do quite a bit of auth beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

since contact is a shared data. you have to to use `content providers` to update conact. Refer this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html